# Access iOS Keychain from iPhone Settings app

Tags: iphone, encryption, settings, nsuserdefaults, keychain

Here is my situation...

I want my password to be encrypted and at the same time I want it to be in iPhone settings (by adding resource and accessing it through NSUserDefaults), but i think NSUserDefaults saves the password or information in plane text and iPhone takes care of everything in its Settings app if there is any change or whatever.

How could I make sure that information that I see in the Settings is coming from and going back to Keychain but before that, Is it possible? If not any other way? May be writing encrypted file?
I DO NOT want settings to be in my app.

### thank you

us

Comment: iOS will send an NSUserDefaultsDidChangeNotification whenever the user defaults (settings) has changed, to your app, when it is run or brought back to foreground.  But you will have to handle Keychain Services in your own app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Keychain service cannot be invoked from within Settings, you need to do this within your app. It is good practice to ask users for their password within your app in a login page or UIAlertView at least (like the App Store does).

From the user's point of view, they don't want to have to launch Settings, enter their password, and then launch your app to log in, they want to do it all in one place.